# asp.net usercontrol development/implementation

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I've developed an ASP.NET user control, instances of which may appear several times on a single page. Without getting into too much application detail, when the value of any one of the instances changes, all of the other instances need to be refreshed.  Currently, in order to accomplish this, I'm requiring that the consuming page implement a couple of methods which iterate through each control on the form, find all the instances of my user control, and call a Refresh method in each one.
    Functionally, it's working perfectly.  However, I'd like to force the developer of the consuming page to implement these two methods exactly as per my requirements.  I could have them implement an interface, but that doesn't provide the functionality in each method.  Or I could have them extend an abstract class, but in either case (interface or abstract class) how can I force them to inherit?  I need something that will trigger a compiler error if the necessary abstract class is not extended by the consuming page.  Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can enforce implementation by using '[abstract methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)' in C# or using the '[MustInherit](http://www.prestwood.com/aspsuite/kb/document_view.asp?qid=101348)' keyword in VB.NET.

In your particular case, you're expecting the developer to essentially implement 'your' code to force the refreshing and this is something I wouldn't want delegate.  Without knowing too many details I would be tempted to utilise the '[Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)' design pattern or possibly the '[Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)' using either a separate object as a controller or even applying the controlling / publishing code to the webpage.  Here's a practical example of the ['Observer' in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42255/Observer-Pattern-in-ASP-NET).

HTH